# Primefaces sum the particular column to show in footer

Tags: primefaces, datatable

I am using PrimeFaces 6.0 in my application.I use one of my page like bank challan.If user has type count to caluclate amount and total amount.

```
<p:column headerText="Denomination">
<h:outputText value="#{bank.denominationAmt}"/>
</p:column>
<p:column headerText="Count">
<p:inputText value="#{bank.count}"/>
</p:column>
<p:column headerText="Amount">
<p:inputText value="#{bank.amt}"/>
</p:column>
....
```

I need to user type count or amount to javascript or primefaces to show sum of amount  show in footerText is possible?

Comment: The datatables tag is plain wrong. PrimeFaces datatable is not based on the jquery datatables.

Answer (score 5):

You have to calculate totals in managed bean, then add a `columnGroup` in footer to show'em :

```
<p:columnGroup type="footer">
    <p:row>
        <p:column style="text-align:right" footerText="Totals:" />
        <p:column style="text-align:right" footerText="#{managedBean.amount}" />
         ...
         ...
    </p:row>
</p:columnGroup>
```

you need to set `p:ajax` with change event in the amount inputtext to recalculate the sum of amount and update the total column.

Comment: I need Keypress in count or amount text  box to calculate in sum of  Amount column to show in footer Text.It will possible in Primefaces component or Javascript

Comment: @BillyHope I tried your solution and it worked perfectly